# jQuery: pass $(this) to a function

Tags: jquery

How can I pass the $(this) object to a function that looks like this

```
$('#selected').click(dosomething)
```

Where dosomething is the function. I tried doing things like...

```
$('#selected').click(dosomething($(this)))
```

But it seems like I'm doing it the wrong way...

Comment: what does `$(this)` refer to in this case? (and no, you can't pass it that way.)

Comment: Inside a click event handler, the `this` is the DOM element that was clicked on.

Comment: @LeeMeador Right, but he isn't inside a click event handler yet. My guess is he's binding this click event handler inside of another event, which is probably a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: The JavaScript `apply` and `call` might be interesting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `dosomething` accepts as argument a jQuery object, then you can do this :

```
$('#selected').click(function(){
    dosomething($(this))
});
```

Comment: Yes, I want `dosomething` to accept a jquery object argument, in this case the `$('#selected')`. About the code, is that the only way I can pass `$(this)`? Meaning passing $(this) to the `$('#selected').click(dosomething)` format is not possible? Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Within the event handler jQuery will assign `this` to the selected element.  Be aware that it is not a jQuery object at that point, so you need to wrap it with `$()`.

```
$('#selected').click(function(){
   dosomething($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually not so far.  You already are in the $(this) scope when you add an event. So all you have to do is this:

```
$('#selected').click(function() {
 // $(this) is the same as $('#selected')
});
```

And let say you want an "outside" function like this:

```
function click_trigger(e) {
  // e for EVENT
  var $this = $(e.target) // The targeted selector ($('#selected'))
  // OR
  var $this = $(e.currentTarget) // The current clicked item (which might have "bubbled" to #selected)
}
$('#selected').click(click_trigger);
```

You can look the jquery documentation for more information on the "event" parameter

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to acomplish:

This will be solid and will give you this of the outside:

```
$this = $(this);
$('#selected').click(function(){
    dosomething($this);
})
```

This is suffcient if you want to pass this meaning "#selected" element:

```
$('#selected').click(function(){
    dosomething($(this));
})
```

Or you can do this to run dosomething in the context of "#selected" element:

```
$('#selected').click(function(){
    dosomething.call(this);
})
```

The last will allow to use `this` inside `dosomething` function which will mean "#selected" element.

Comment: You might want to mention that he can do `var currentThis = $(this);` and then use that saved `this` value.